# How to display the values set by the karate-config.js file in the karate report？

Tags: karate

I want to display the value of variable name set in the js file in the karate html report. What should I do? Who can answer me? Thank you

[For example, the "baseUrl" in the report is set in karate-config.js. I want it to display the value I set in karate-config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPmO2.png)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just do this on the first line:

```
* print 'baseUrl is:', baseUrl
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to display the value of baseUrl after "Given url". What can I do in this case?

Comment: @user20026100 just put the `print` wherever you want. otherwise please consider what you want not supported by karate, you are welcome to contribute code